# Runtime Error with Image Transport in Eclipse IDE

Tags: ros, eclipse, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have configured the Eclipse as my IDE and I am having no problems during compile time for my ROS packages. Once I run or enter the Debug mode, if there is an image_transport object use, it will immediately cause runtime error showing this error message:

> [rospack] Error: package 'image_transport' not found
> [librospack]: error while executing command
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::ClassLoaderException'
> what():  Unable to find package: image_transport

When I try to run the same node outside the Eclipse environment I have no such problems.
Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255116/runtime-error-with-image-transport-in-eclipse-ide/) by [Albtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5273/albtech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have your `.bashrc` environment properly sourced. As stated in the documentation, you should load your `.bashrc` environment with Eclipse, by launching it from the command line via `$ bash -i -c "eclipse"` . For convenience, you can also set this automatically by changing the `Exec=` line in your *eclipse.desktop* launcher.

For example, I did

```
$ vim ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
```

For example, my *eclipse.desktop* file contains this:

```
Exec=bash -i -c /MY_PATH_TO_ECLIPSE/eclipse
```

Then, you may drag this *eclipse.desktop* file to the side bar.

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0